# How to remotely query sas7bdat file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, ssh, sas, paramiko

I am trying to query a database stored in SAS's sas7bdat file format using Python (I don't have SAS).  The sas7bdat file is stored on a remote server that I can access through an SSH connection with paramiko, but is too large to simply read with Python's sas7bdat module or to download locally.

Can anyone think of a way to use the SSH connection to *query* the sas7bdat file, and load the query results into Python (Pandas DataFrame, etc)?  Or perhaps a completely different approach?

Comment: Do you have permissions to write scripts on the server?

Comment: Yes, and the server (which is old) has python 2.6.4 installed.

Comment: But it does not have the sas7bdat Python module installed, nor do I have permission to install it.

Comment: do you have SAS/SHARE licensed?  If so, is this available via a Share library?

Comment: No, I don't have any SAS products.

Comment: How was the SAS data set generated, then?  The point of my question is that if the SAS server has a SAS/SHARE or SAS Integration Technologies license, then there are options for you to access the data (JDBC, a C library proved by SAS, etc.).

Comment: The SAS data set was generated by another user and placed on the server (a long time ago).  The server itself doesn't have a SAS implementation.

Comment: does the server have the pandas library installed? It does have the pandas.read_sas method according to this: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sas.html)

Answer (score 0):

`.sas7bdat` is a proprietary database format that must be reverse-engineered to access. If you do not have the sas7bdat Python module installed, you will be unable to query it without making a custom script that can read the file. This is assuming that the file is uncompressed; if it is compressed, you'll have a harder time being able to read it.

I would recommend reading through the [Python sas7bdat script](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sas7bdat) and [R code](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sas7bdat/index.html) to get an idea of exactly how to read the file.

An easier solution would be to get access to install the sas7bdat file; if it is crucial enough to the work you're doing, your admins will give you permission.

Comment: To be clear, I have the sas7bdat module installed on my own machine.  However, the server on which the .sas7bdat file is stored does not have that module (and is not currently maintained).  If the .sas7bdat file were small, I'd just download it and read it, but unfortunately it is too large to transfer or load.  Therefore I would like to query it, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Carolina S-JDBC](http://www.dullesresearch.com/sjdbc-intro/) to query the sas7bdat files. It supports SQL syntax so you can subset your data and works well in different language environment including Python:

```
import jaydebeapi

conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.dullesopen.jdbc.Driver',
         'jdbc:carolina:v2:libnames=(dir=\'./mydata\')',
         'sjdbc/carolina-jdbc-2.0.4.jar')
curs = conn.cursor()
# select a subset of data
curs.execute( "SELECT * FROM big_sasfile WHERE id < 1000")
# replace with saving to a file
print curs.fetchall()

conn.close()
```

If you don't have `jaydebeapi` Python module either and cannot get it installed without the root access, you can write a small Java program to run your query against the sas7bdat file using the driver.

S-JDBC is a self-contained jar file, so you don't need any permissions beyond your home directory to "install" it.

**Disclaimer:** Carolina S-JDBC is a commercial product by Dulles Research with free evaluation. I work for Dulles Research.